# TS error with @Injectable tag Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I am running into this error when compiling my code:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class TaskService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  getTasks() {
    return this.http.get('/api/tasks');
  }
}
```

ERROR in src/app/tasks/task.service.ts(4,1): error TS1238: Unable to resolve signature of class decorator when called as an expression.

I'm not sure where it's going wrong... 4,1 is the @ symbol before Injectable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding a `return` type `getTasks(): Observable<any>`. 
Do you inject the `HttpClientModule` correctly ?

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    // Include it under 'imports' in your application module
    // after BrowserModule.
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
})
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. error was caused by not having the return type and another underlying error was caused by not injecting HttpClientModule correctly. Both fixed. Going through an angular Cli tutorial right now which is on Angular 4 so some of these things have been different/deprecated. Thanks!

Comment: The return type should not cause this error. However its better to define the return type if the function actually returns something.

Comment: Angular 5 is more strict than before :)